# Binary tree of processes

Tags: c, recursion, process, fork, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a recursive function that uses fork() to create a binary tree structure of father-child processes, given the number of levels of the tree. So far I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void createTree(int level){

    pid_t leftson;
    pid_t rightson;

    if (level > 1){


        if ((leftson = fork()) < 0) {
             perror("fork:");
             exit(1);
        }   // Create the first son

        if (leftson == 0){
            createTree(level--);
        } // If I'm the left son, continue biulding the structure

        else { // I'm father

            if ((rightson = fork()) < 0) {
                 perror("fork:");
                 exit(1);
            } // Create right son

            if (rightson == 0){
                createTree(level--);
            } // I'm right, continue building

            else printf("created my 2 sons"); // I'm the father

        } 




    }
    else if (level == 1){
        printf("end of tree");
    }   




}


void main(){

    createTree(3);

}
```

The problem is that the program enters in an infinite loop of creating processes because the level variable never decreases, I'm thinking of using pipes but I don't know how to use them when there are so many processes.

Also, Is there a way to give the new processes arguments like I would from bash? Instead of using pipes?

Answer (score 1):

try using `createTree(level-1);` instead of `createTree(level--);` as sometimes, this can cause infinite loops in recursive calls.